# Xamarin.Forms.Maps Pin event to command

Tags: xamarin.forms

How can i add events to the pins from Xamarin.forms.maps without breaking the MVVM pattern? I cannot add event to command behavior because the pin doesn't have behaviors

````
<customMap:BindableMap x:Name="map" ItemsSource="{Binding Pins, Mode=TwoWay}" MapSpan="{Binding MapSpan}" Polyline="{Binding RoutePolyline}">
            <customMap:BindableMap.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <maps:Pin Position="{Binding Position}"
                              Label="{Binding Label}" 
                              Address="{Binding Address}"
                              Type="{Binding Type}" 
                              MarkerClicked="{Binding MarkerClicked}"/> // this doesn't work
                </DataTemplate>
            </customMap:BindableMap.ItemTemplate>
        </customMap:BindableMap>
``` this custom map i made supports mapspan and polyline bindings
````

Comment: have the MarkerClicked handler call a VM command

Comment: do u mean to call a vm method from the code behind? isn't that breaking the mvvm?

Comment: No, why would it, and even if it did, so what?  Patterns are not infallible laws of software engineering that can never be broken.

Comment: I know that's working but i also want to find a solution that's not breaking mvvm.

Comment: The code behind is part of the View.  Why does calling a VM method from the code behind "break" MVVM but binding a VM command from a view does not?

Comment: Maybe you're right, But then why they created the event to command behavior in the docs? They could've just used the code behind to call methods from the VM, right?

Comment: What does your custom map look like? It seems strange to add Pin into DataTemplate.